# Map from Class[T] to T without casting

Tags: scala

I want to map from class tokens to instances along the lines of the following code:

```
trait Instances {
  def put[T](key: Class[T], value: T)
  def get[T](key: Class[T]): T
}
```

Can this be done without having to resolve to casts in the get method?

**Update:**

How could this be done for the more general case with some `Foo[T]` instead of `Class[T]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this without *any* casting (even within `get`) then you will need to write a heterogeneous map.  For reasons that should be obvious, this is tricky.  :-)  The easiest way would probably be to use a `HList`-like structure and build a `find` function.  However, that's not trivial since you need to define some way of checking type equality for two arbitrary types.

I attempted to get a little tricky with tuples and existential types.  However, Scala doesn't provide a unification mechanism (pattern matching doesn't work).  Also, subtyping ties the whole thing in knots and basically eliminates any sort of safety it might have provided:

```
val xs: List[(Class[A], A) forSome { type A }] = List(
  classOf[String] -> "foo", classOf[Int] -> 42)

val search = classOf[String]
val finalResult = xs collect { case (`search`, result) => result } headOption
```

In this example, `finalResult` will be of type `Any`.  This is actually rightly so, since subtyping means that we don't really know *anything* about `A`.  It's not why the compiler is choosing that type, but it is a correct choice.  Take for example:

```
val xs: List[(Class[A], A) forSome { type A }] = List(classOf[Boolean] -> 'bippy)
```

<del>This is totally legal!  Subtyping means that `A` in this case will be chosen as `Any`.  It's hardly what we want, but it is what you will get.  Thus, in order to express this constraint *without* tracking all of the types individual (using a `HMap`), Scala would need to be able to express the constraint that a type is a *specific* type and nothing else.  Unfortunately, Scala does not have this ability, and so we're basically stuck on the generic constraint front.</del>

**Update**  Actually, it's not legal.  Just tried it and the compiler kicked it out.  I think that only worked because `Class` is invariant in its type parameter.  So, if `Foo` is a definite type that is invariant, you should be safe from this case.  It still doesn't solve the unification problem, but at least it's sound.  Unfortunately, type constructors are assumed to be in a magical super-position between co-, contra- and invariance, so if it's *truly* an arbitrary type `Foo` of kind `* => *`, then you're still sunk on the existential front.

In summary: it should be possible, but only if you fully encode `Instances` as a `HMap`.  Personally, I would just cast inside `get`.  Much simpler!

Answer (score 9):

You can try retrieving the object from your map as an `Any`, then using your `Class[T]` to “cast reflectively”:

```
trait Instances {                                        
  private val map = collection.mutable.Map[Class[_], Any]()
  def put[T](key: Class[T], value: T) { map += (key -> value) }
  def get[T](key: Class[T]): T = key.cast(map(key))        
}
```

Comment: Impressive feature, will refactor some code asap :) thanks Jean-Philipe

Comment: You can't avoid casting without reified type, but this technic look really safe to me.

Comment: @michid Indeed, you can't avoid casting. What `key.cast(obj)` does here is really a checked `(T) obj` cast. The `cast` method will also throw a `ClassCastException` if you give it something that's not an instance of `T`.

Answer (score 5):

With help of a friend of mine, we defined the map with keys as Manifest instead of Class which gives a better api when calling.

I didnt get your updated question about "general case with some Foo[T] instead of Class[T]". But this should work for the cases you specified.

```
object Instances {                                        
  private val map = collection.mutable.Map[Manifest[_], Any]()
  def put[T: Manifest](value: T) = map += manifest[T] -> value
  def get[T: Manifest]: T = map(manifest[T]).asInstanceOf[T]

  def main (args: Array[String] ) {
    put(1)
    put("2")
    println(get[Int])
    println(get[String])
  }
}
```