# Relating parameterized types

Tags: generics, scala

I have a map where both the keys and values are generic types. Something like this:

```
Map[Foo[A], Bar[A]]
```

What I'd like to express is that the type `A` may be different for each key-value pair in the map, but every key is always parameterized with the same type as the value that it maps to. So a `Foo[Int]` always maps to a `Bar[Int]`, a `Foo[String]` always maps to a `Bar[String]`, and so forth.

Does anyone know a way to express this?

**EDIT:**

Here's an example of the sort of thing I'm trying to do:

```
trait Parameter // not important what it actually does

class Example {
  val handlers: Map[_ <: Parameter, (_ <: Parameter) => _] = Map()

  def doSomething() {
    for ((value, handler) <- handlers) {
      handler(value)
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is that a value will always map to a function that can accept it as a parameter, but as the code is written now, the compiler can't know this.

Comment: That line doesn't compile by itself, scala needs to pick those types from somewhere (either a class or method type annotation, or an abstract type) could you show us the code?

Comment: This is a near duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401329/map-from-classtto-t-without-casting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, it is possible to define a heterogeneous map in Scala. Here's a rough sketch:

```
class HMap[A[_], B[_]] extends Iterable[HMap.Mapping[A, B, _]] {
  private val self = mutable.Map[A[_], B[_]]()

  def toMapping[T](a: A[_], b: B[_]): HMap.Mapping[A, B, T] = {
    HMap.Mapping(a.asInstanceOf[A[T]], b.asInstanceOf[B[T]])
  }

  def iterator: Iterator[HMap.Mapping[A, B, _]] =
    new Iterator[HMap.Mapping[A, B, _]] {
      val sub = self.iterator

      def hasNext = sub.hasNext
      def next(): HMap.Mapping[A, B, _] = {
        val (key, value) = sub.next()
        toMapping(key, value)
      }
    }

  def update[T](key: A[T], value: B[T]) = (self(key) = value)
  def get[T](key: A[T]) = self.get(key).asInstanceOf[Option[B[T]]]
  def apply[T](key: A[T]) = self(key).asInstanceOf[B[T]]
}

object HMap {
  case class Mapping[A[_], B[_], T](val key: A[T], val value: B[T])
}
```

This could be made completely typesafe by internally using a linked list of mappings instead of a map, but this is better for performance.

My original example would look like this:

```
object Example {
  type Identity[T] = T
  type Handler[T] = (T) => _

  val handlers = new HMap[Identity, Handler]

  def doSomething() {
    for (HMap.Mapping(value, handler) <- handlers) {
      handler(value)
    }
  }
}
```

This is almost perfect, except I'm not sure how to add bounds.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to describe a sort of [higher-rank polymorphic](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/higher-rank-polymorphism-in-scala/), heterogeneous map, where each key-value pair in the map can have a different type parameter.  As cool as it would be, Scala's type system doesn't allow you to express this statically.  I think the best you can do is to define some horrible, unsafe helper methods:

```scala
def get [A] (map: Map[Foo[_], Bar[_]], k: Foo[A]) : Bar[A] 
def put [A] (map: Map[Foo[_], Bar[_]], k: Foo[A], v: Bar[A])
```

You might be able to make it somewhat more safe using `Manifest`s to reify the type parameters of each key-value pair at runtime, but I'm not sure how...

Comment: They should arguably be methods in an object encapsulating the unsafe map — then the user would get a safer interface (or even a safe one, if entries can only be inserted through this interface; but this is often too restrictive). No manifests are needed for the base interface. The implementation needs to use casts of course, but you can ensure they won't fail.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a map that does what you want. You can find some basic documentation on it here: https://github.com/sullivan-/emblem/wiki/TypeBoundMaps

TypeBoundMaps take types with a single type parameter, so you will need to introduce a couple of new types for your key and value types in the map:

```
trait Parameter
type Identity[P <: Parameter] = P
type Handler[P <: Parameter] = (P) => _
```

Now you can create the map you want like so:

```
var handlers = TypeBoundMap[Parameter, Identity, Handler]()
```

Here's a couple of examples of using the map:

```
trait P1 extends Parameter
trait P2 extends Parameter

val p1: P1 = new P1 {}
val f1: Handler[P1] = { p1: P1 => () }

handlers += p1 -> f1 // add a new pair to the map                                                             
val f2: Handler[P1] = handlers(p1) // retrieve a value from the map
```

Now, to imitate the for loop in your example, we need to bring in a new type `TypeBoundPair`, which is a key-value pair where the parameter values match:

```
def handle[P <: Parameter](pair: TypeBoundPair[Parameter, Identity, Handler, P]): Unit = {
  pair._2(pair._1)
}

handlers.foreach { pair => handle(pair) }
```

The idea behind introducing the `Identity` and `Handler` types is explained in more detail here: http://tinyurl.com/multi-tparam

Answer (score -2):

```
scala> trait MyPair {
     | type T
     | val key:Foo[T]
     | val value:Bar[T]
     | }
defined trait MyPair

scala> var l:List[MyPair] = _
l: List[MyPair] = null

scala> l = List(new MyPair{type T = Int; val key = new Foo[Int]{}; val value = new Bar[Int]{} })
l: List[MyPair] = List($anon$1@176bf9e)

scala> l = List(new MyPair{type T = Int; val key = new Foo[Int]{}; val value = new Bar[Int]{} }, new MyPair {type T = String; val key = new Foo[String]{}; val value = new Bar[String]{} })
l: List[MyPair] = List($anon$1@d78fb4, $anon$4@1b72da)

scala> l = List(new MyPair{type T = Int; val key = new Foo[Int]{}; val value = new Bar[Int]{} }, new MyPair {type T = String; val key = new Foo[String]{}; val value = new Bar[Int]{} })
<console>:11: error: overriding value value in trait MyPair of type Bar[this.T];
 value value has incompatible type
       l = List(new MyPair{type T = Int; val key = new Foo[Int]{}; val value = new Bar[Int]{} }, new MyPair {type T = String; val key = new Foo[String]{}; val value = new Bar[Int]{} })
```