# How to return correct type from generic function passed a related abstract type parameter

Tags: scala

I am trying to write "better" (more idiomatic?) Scala code for the following circumstance:
I have a set of classes that will be identified by a reference field that belongs to a parallel set of reference case classes, something like the following:

```
abstract sealed class Ref(value: String)

case class ARef(value: String) extends Ref(value)
case class BRef(value: String) extends Ref(value)
case class CRef(value: String) extends Ref(value)

trait Referenced {
  type refType <: Ref
  val ref: refType
}

trait A extends Referenced { type refType = ARef }
trait B extends Referenced { type refType = BRef }
trait C extends Referenced { type refType = CRef }
```

Another class (which will probably turn into the state type of a State monad) will contain lists of these types, and provide a function to retrieve an object, given its reference. I want this returned value to be appropriately typed, i.e. given

```
val aRef = ARef("my A ref")
```

I want to be able to make a call like:

```
val myA: Option[A] = context.get[A](aRef)
```

and be sure to get back an Option[A], not just an Option[Referenced]. My best attempt to achieve this so far looks something like the following:

```
trait Context {

  // ... other stuff ...

  protected val aList: List[A]
  protected val bList: List[B]
  protected val cList: List[C]

  def get[R <: Referenced](ref: R#refType): Option[R] = {
    val result = ref match {
      case aRef: ARef => aList.find(_.ref == aRef)
      case bRef: BRef => bList.find(_.ref == bRef)
      case cRef: CRef => cList.find(_.ref == cRef)
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Ref type for retrieval: "+ref)
    }
    result.asInstanceOf[Option[R]]
  }
}
```

which seems to work correctly, but has that smelly "asInstanceOf" call in it. I would be interested in seeing ideas on how this might be done better (and check that I haven't just missed an obvious simpler solution).

Note that for other reasons, I have thus far elected to go with abstract typing rather than parameter types (`trait A extends Referenced[ARef]` style), but could change this if the reasons were compelling enough.

Comment: Essentially [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897376/relating-parameterized-types) or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401329/map-from-classtto-t-without-casting). Perhaps you could use [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless#heterogenous-maps)'s `HMap`. I think if you don't throw in a heavy type manipulation tool like Shapeless, you'll have to cast at some point, so your solution should be ok.

Comment: Could `Referenced` be `sealed` as well?

Comment: Thanks @0__, checking out those other questions I think I would agree with you - either I start pulling in Shapeless and do some heavy manipulation involving something like HMap, or accept a cast which is at least confined to within the called method. As for sealing Referenced, that works for the "toy" classes as I presented above for the purpose of the question, but in reality my intended functionality makes them much more complex beasts, defined in their own files.

Comment: Also, [if you look at the implementation](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/hmap.scala#L29), you see that it doesn't avoid casting. It just handles the "danger" for you, so you can't make mistakes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The machinery needed to do this without casting really isn't all that heavy in this case ... it's just another example of a [functional dependency](http://www.chuusai.com/2011/07/16/fundeps-in-scala/).

In what follows we rely on the fact that type `Ref` is sealed so that we can simply enumerate the alternatives. Your `Ref` and `Reference` hierarchies remain unchanged, and we add a relation type `Rel` to both express the type-level correspondence between the two, and to make an appropriate value-level selection,

```
trait Rel[Ref, T] {
  def lookup(as: List[A], bs: List[B], cs: List[C])(ref: Ref) : Option[T]
}

object Rel {
  implicit val relA = new Rel[ARef, A] {
    def lookup(as: List[A], bs: List[B], cs: List[C])(ref: ARef) : Option[A] =
      as.find(_.ref == ref)
  }
  implicit val relB = new Rel[BRef, B] {
    def lookup(as: List[A], bs: List[B], cs: List[C])(ref: BRef) : Option[B] =
      bs.find(_.ref == ref)
  }
  implicit val relC = new Rel[CRef, C] {
    def lookup(as: List[A], bs: List[B], cs: List[C])(ref: CRef) : Option[C] =
      cs.find(_.ref == ref)
  }
}
```

Now we can reimplement `Context` without pattern matches or casts as follows,

```
trait Context {

  // ... other stuff ...

  protected val aList: List[A] = ???
  protected val bList: List[B] = ???
  protected val cList: List[C] = ???

  def get[R <: Ref, T](ref: R)(implicit rel: Rel[R, T]): Option[T] =
    rel.lookup(aList, bList, cList)(ref)
}
```

And we can use this new definition like so,

```
object Test {
  def typed[T](t: => T) {}     // For pedagogic purposes only

  val context = new Context {}

  val aRef = ARef("my A ref")
  val myA = context.get(aRef)
  typed[Option[A]](myA)        // Optional: verify inferred type of myA

  val bRef = BRef("my B ref")
  val myB = context.get(bRef)
  typed[Option[B]](myB)        // Optional: verify inferred type of myB

  val cRef = CRef("my C ref")
  val myC = context.get(cRef)
  typed[Option[C]](myC)        // Optional: verify inferred type of myC
}
```

Notice that the resolution of the implicit `Rel` argument to `get` computes the type of the corresponding `Reference` from the type of the `ref` argument, so we're able to avoid having to use any explicit type arguments at `get`'s call-sites.

Comment: Great! So this works if the key is sealed. Are there any other options if that was not the case, other than hiding the casting as in Shapeless' `HMap`?

Comment: Casting can only be avoided if `Context` is indexed somehow or another by the complete set of key types. Currently that's entailed by the explicit set of key-type-specific list members (ie. `aList`, `bList` etc.). It could also be captured by parametrizing `Context` with the types of the keys where that's known. For that you'd want `Context` to be instantiated with an `HList` type parameter (ie. `Context[A :: B :: C :: ... :: HNil]`) and the individual list members would be replaced by an `HList` of lists of specific types ... at which point things are getting quite a bit more heavyweight.

Comment: Ah, quite neat. On first reading I wasn't convinced about letting Ref know about the Referenced hierarchy, or exposing the `typed[T]` method and calls in all the places where I expect I will be making this type of call, but those are probably minor quibbles so I'll give this a try and see if I can't make the calls look cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: @ShadowlandsI think you might be misreading slightly: I haven't changed `Ref` or `Reference` in any way so it's not the case that "Ref know(s) about the Referenced hierarchy" ... the correspondence is captured by the `Rel` instances. Also `typed[T]` is completely optional ... it's there solely to verify that type inference has done the right thing. The reason I use it is to avoid any possibility that an explicit type annotation on the val definitions might influence type inference on the RHS.

Comment: @Miles You're right - I just realised I was reading Rel as Ref.

Comment: Quite a bit of boilerplate detected in `object Rel` :)

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to reiterate my own (current) "answer" for my question, because I thought it would be interesting/instructive to allow readers to vote it up or down to generate a more direct comparison with answers provided by others.

```
trait Context {

  // ... other stuff ...

  protected val aList: List[A]
  protected val bList: List[B]
  protected val cList: List[C]

  def get[R <: Referenced](ref: R#refType): Option[R] = {
    val result = ref match {
      case aRef: ARef => aList.find(_.ref == aRef)
      case bRef: BRef => bList.find(_.ref == bRef)
      case cRef: CRef => cList.find(_.ref == cRef)
      case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Unknown Ref type for retrieval: "+ref)
    }
    result.asInstanceOf[Option[R]]
  }
}
```